# I cannot install Django, And give "Installation failled"

Tags: python, django, backend

I want to install Django,But when I run `pipenv install django` it create virtual environment and then give  `Installation Failed`.

Before try below codes I  run `pip install django` to install Django. And there is no issue with internet connection.

How do I fix this?

I tried  `pip install django`  , `pipenv install django`

Comment: Could you share the complete error traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to your desired folder, then:

```
# Creates the virtual environment
python -m venv venv

# Activate your venv
Mac/Linux: source venv/bin/activate
Windows: .\venv\Scripts\activate

# Update pip and install django
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install Django
```

Remember that virual environment is an isolated space, so you are going to need to activate it everytime you work on that specific project, else the libraries will not be found.

Comment: I used `pip install --upgrade pip` command to upgrade my pip version as you mentioned. after that Django was installed. Thank You for your support.